# Alert someone to something, something to someone, or both?

Tags: prepositions

which is correct: "Alert someone to a mistake", or "Alert a mistake to someone?"

Answer (score 2):

I think you alert a person and not a thing, so the first one must be the correct phrase.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the correct way is, "Alert someone **of** a mistake."